# Check for a particular string in stdin

Tags: c++, pipe, signals

I have a small problem that I don't know how to solve.

I have a program which is basically commanded by inputs in stdin. It just keeps running until receives a particular string and then do something else. Ok, *I don't have access to the code that controls these inputs* but I would like to add a new command.

The idea I have is the following:

. Create a pipe in my program

. Fork the process

. One of them goes on with the the original program while the other reads from stdin.

. Redirect stdin of process that continued the usual execution to the pipe.

. The part that keeps listening from stdin, checks what is receives, if it is not the new command, just redirect the pipe (so that the old commands still work)

. If it is the new command, send a particular signal.

I've been thinking about implementing that with pipe/fork/dup2 in c++, but I don't know how I would send and catch a signal in the process that continued the execution. How can I do that in c++? Do you guys have any suggestion? Does this might work?

Comment: why not a simple command line: `myprog | prog_being_commanded` ?

Comment: Indeed. Use a script to do the piping if you want a simpler command.

Answer (score 0):

Your program should just do following:

1. read data from `stdin`.
2. search for new command string. if found, do some job.
3. send all your processed input to `stdout` (or all data except extracted command data, depending on your needs)

And it shoulde be executed like this:

`$ cat input.txt | my_prog | other_prog`

All input which is not handled by your program, will go to existing program, as it is got from input.txt (of course, data source could be arbitrary, not necessarily file).